# Tokenizing a letter as an operator

Tags: ply

I need to make a language that has variables in it, but it also needs the letter 'd' to be an operand that has a number on the right and maybe a number on the left. I thought that making sure the lexer checks for the letter first would give it precedence, but that doesn't happen and i don't know why.

```py
from ply import lex, yacc

tokens=['INT', 'D', 'PLUS', 'MINUS', 'LPAR', 'RPAR', 'BIGGEST', 'SMALLEST', 'EQ', 'NAME']

t_PLUS     = r'\+'
t_MINUS    = r'\-'
t_LPAR     = r'\('
t_RPAR     = r'\)'
t_BIGGEST  = r'\!'
t_SMALLEST = r'\#'
t_D        = r'[dD]'
t_EQ       = r'\='
t_NAME     = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'

def t_INT(t):
    r'[0-9]\d*'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t


def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += 1


t_ignore = ' \t'

def t_error(t):
    print("Not recognized by the lexer:", t.value)
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = lex.lex()

while True:
    try: s = input(">> ")
    except EOFError: break
    lexer.input(s)
    while True:
        t = lexer.token()
        if not t: break
        print(t)
```

If i write:
`3d4` 
it outputs:

```
LexToken(INT,3,1,0)
LexToken(NAME,'d4',1,1)
```

and i don't know how to work around it.

Comment: So in your language, `d4` is *never* an identifier, although `e4` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ply does not prioritize token variables by order of appearance; rather, it orders them in decreasing order by length (longest first). So your `t_NAME` pattern will come before `t_D`. This is explained in the [Ply manual](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn6), along with a concrete example of how to handle reserved words (which may not apply in your case).

If I understand correctly, the letter `d` cannot be an identifier, and neither can `d` followed by a number. It is not entirely clear to me whether you expect `d2e` to be a plausible identifier, but for simplicity I'm assuming that the answer is "No", in which case you can easily restrict the `t_NAME` regular expression by requiring an initial `d` to be followed by another letter:

```
t_NAME = '([a-ce-zA-CE-Z_]|[dD][a-zA-Z_])[a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
```

If you wanted to allow `d2e` to be a name, then you could go with:

```
t_NAME = '([a-ce-zA-CE-Z_]|[dD][0-9]*[a-zA-Z_])[a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
```